# Android Studio - показ вариантов завершения при написании кода

Tags: android-studio

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить Android Studio? Где поставить заветную галочку? При написании кода (например пишу OnCl), у меня не разворачиваются варианты его завершения(чтобы я мог выбрать OnClick). Помогите это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File - Settings - Editor - General - Code Completion

[image: Скриншот]